# Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains on local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, subdomain

I know a cookie can be shared across multiple subdomains using the setting

```
<forms 
    name=".ASPXAUTH" 
    loginUrl="Login/" 
    protection="Validation" 
    timeout="120" 
    path="/"     
    domain=".mydomain.com"/>
```

in Web.config. But how to replicate same thing  on local machine. I am using windows 7 and IIS 7 on my laptop. So I have sites localhost.users/ for my actual site users.mysite.com
localhost.host/ for host.mysite.com and similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`localhost.users` and `localhost.host` is cross domain. Cookies cannot be shared cross domain.

You could configure it like this so that the sub-domain differs but the root domain stays the same:

- `users.localhost`
- `host.localhost`

Now set the cookie domain in your web.config to `localhost`:

```
domain=".localhost"
```

and in your `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file add the following 2 entries:

```
127.0.0.1 users.localhost
127.0.0.1 host.localhost
```

Now you will be able to successfully share the authentication cookie between `users.localhost` and `host.localhost`.

Ah, and don't forget to put a step in your automated build process that will transform your web.config value to the correct root domain before shipping in production.

Comment: Thanks Darin, How to set this up in IIS as I created these sites from visual studio.

Comment: @Parminder, IIS configuration questions should be discussed on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Darin, Thanks, I have asked this question there, but does it make sense to ask the same question at two differnt places.

Answer (score 3):

This is a reminder for anyone running in Framework 4.5 and trying to share the token with frameworks 4 and lower, please notice that this will cause you not to receive the auth cookie on any of the 4 and lower apps. ie: if in your `web.config` you have:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="80480" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

You can get it to work by removing the `targetFramework="4.5"` attribute to get it to work, though I don't know if there are any side effects in doing so:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="80480" />
```

Comment: This saved me on a pair of websites that use .NET 4.5.1!

Comment: I was unable work authentication on a sub application. It's work with targetFramework="4.5" in the 2 web.config files. Thanks