# How to use subdomains with localhost on IISExpress?

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost, iis-express

I'm serving my MVC app locally via localhost:5252 right now.

I'm trying to set up my app to test multi-tenancy by having both localhost and contoso.localhost point to my web app instance.

I set up my hosts file with the corresponding entry:

```
127.0.0.1       contoso.localhost
```

However I'm not sure what else I need to do to make this work.  Right now I just get a standard IIS8 page when I navigate, even though I haven't done anything in IIS Manager.

I'm trying to avoid having to use IIS locally, as everything is working with IISExpress.  Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains on local IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278015/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains-on-local-iis)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This can be accomplished by editing the applicationHost.config file

```
C:\Users\yourProfile\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
```

Visual Studio usually handles editing this file for you when you make configuration changes, but you can manually edit. Find the particular site you are working with and the following bindings should work:

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5252:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5252:contoso.localhost" />
</bindings>
```

You can really change the port to anything you want so you could use 80 to save yourself some typing. Continue adding bindings to fill out your multi-tenancy as needed.

If you are looking for more information, I would recommend checking out [Scott Hanselman's blog post on IIS Express & SSL.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)

## Update

With VS 2015 & .NET core, the applicationHost.config has moved to a directory based system of storing the configuration instead of a global configuration file. The new location is relative to your project:

`.vs\config\applicationHost.config`

The same editing principals apply to this file, but when using TFS source control VS **does not edit** the file when changing between branches as it did with the global file.

Regarding the wildcard comment for domains, [wildcarding hostname isn't supported](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support) until IIS 10. Therefore, it may be supported in IIS Express 10, but probably not before.

> The breakdown of the `bindingInformation` is:
>
> `bindingInformation="<IPAddress>:<Port>:<Hostname>"`

Comment: My path was actually `C:\Users\myaccount\Documents\IISExpress`

Comment: @SerjSagan Good catch. That is the correct path. I've updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: @beavel I tried this but I am still getting 400 bad request ..any thought?

Comment: @Steve to hard to say without any more details. Did you read through the linked blog post?

Comment: @beavel Sry that I did not. After reading thru it I found that I need to netsh to reserve the port. Got it working after that, thanks

Comment: is it possible to bind `*.localhost`?

Comment: consider you have to run visual studio as administrator and the config file address changed to '\your-Project-root\.vs\config\applicationhost.config' in .NET Core project.

Comment: Didn't work initially. Adding 127.0.0.1 mysub.localhost to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your project settings for the Project URL.

Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Web

Look for Project Url under Servers. Update this value to mirror your subdomain url and you should be good to go.

Comment: I need to be able to use localhost and contoso.localhost at the same time - I don't see a way to configure multiple URLs with this approach. thoughts?