# Mapping Subdomains to Areas in ASP.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-core-3.0

### What I want to achieve

- Mapping my normal domain e.g. `example.com` to no area if possible.
- Mapping my subdomain e.g. `blog.example.com` to a area named `blog`.

#### What I have found

There are actually quite a lot of posts regarding to this topic, especially mapping subdomains to areas.

From SO:

- [area-and-subdomain-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512403/area-and-subdomain-routing)
- [asp-net-core-mapping-subdomains-to-areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287716/asp-net-core-mapping-subdomains-to-areas)

Others:

- [danylkoweb.com](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/using-subdomains-in-aspnet-mvc-DX)
- [benjii.me](https://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/)
- [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170514074637/http://www.mikeminded.net:80/tutorials/webdevelopment/3-mapping-subdomains-to-areas-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

And there are probably even more.

#### Problem

But there is one big problem, in ASP.Net Core 3 they changed a lot of things, one of them being the routing in general, see [mircosoft's devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-4/). Basically they changed it so everything should now be endpoints.

All the classes e.g. `MvcRouteHandler` and interfaces e.g. `IRouter` are basically obsolete now, at least from my understanding. After a while googling around and diggin' in the GitHub repositories I couldn't find anything useful.

#### Additional information

- I am using `SDK 3.0.100-preview6-012264`, but trying to upgrade to
  `SDK 3.0.100-preview7-012821` as soon as possible.
- I am using a reserve proxy (nginx) which passes the request to the ASP.Net Core Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give an update to this whole situation, with the release of .Net Core 3 you can now make use of the [`RequireHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.routingendpointconventionbuilderextensions.requirehost?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method.

This would look something like the following:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name: "Home",
                areaName: "Home",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}")
             .RequireHost("localhost:5001", "sub.domain.com");
}
```

If you remove the `Area` in the pattern parameter, like in the example, you can achieve exactly that. It is still somewhat hacky, but a lot cleaner. 
Note, that you would have to put a `RequireHost` on all of the endpoints in order to get proper default route matching.

Comment: I am getting "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.".Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @Maddy89 you should probably create a new question and link this answer, if you need help.

Answer (score 3):

You said all requests pass on `nginx` but nothing said about nginx redirection, did you try to use `nginx` to do that, just redirect the sub-domain to domain using `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

```
server {
   server_name sub.domain.co;
   location / {
   return 301 $scheme://domain.co/BlogSite$request_uri;
  }
}
```

(`BlogSite` is your area routing on ASP.Net Core Server.)

Comment: Would the URL in the browser stick with the subdomain e.g. `blog.example.com` or would it actually switch the url to example.com/blog/$request_uri?

Comment: @Twenty: That should depend on how you configure nginx. iirc it can also rewrite response urls

Comment: Well if it doesn't rewrite per default it would be perfect. Thanks in advance, will mark it as soon as I can verify it working.

Comment: @Twenty In this case there are two options, `return directive` and `rewrite directive` on `NGINX Rewrite Rules` (i gave return directive example) please check them.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!