# How to route all subdomain on Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to use a different controller when users enter a subdomain. I´m using [RequireHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#host-matching-in-routes-with-requirehost).

How can it works this with any domain? For example I'm using domain.test just for development, but in production I have another.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Subdomain}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireHost("*.domain.test")


    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172884/mapping-subdomains-to-areas-in-asp-net-core-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequireHost` is almost the same as adding `[Host("...")]` attributes everywhere, except that they only apply to that route.

Evaluation of Host rules seems to occur in [HostMatcherPolicy](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0a1d68b8f375eb979c5722b8bedd57496749b1f8/src/Http/Routing/src/Matching/HostMatcherPolicy.cs#L114). Which should treat "*.domain.test" as matching all subdomains, but not the domain itself. You will need to add "domain.test" if you want that to match too.

However, you do have a second route that can match everything. I suspect you will need to explicitly list the valid hosts for your default route. Or split your controllers into different areas to ensure they only match the expected rule.

Comment: I understand, thanks, What happen if I can´t know the domain? I want to route all subdomain on whatever domain

Comment: Wildcard subdomains do seem to be supported. Just note that you need to list domains separately from wildcard subdomains.