# Asp Net Core 2, IIS Express and Subdomain

Tags: subdomain, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express

How to use (localhost)  subdomain? Address localhost:5000 works but test.localhost:5000 not

1. asp core 2
2. IIS Express
3. config: ".vs/config/aplicationhost.config"

   ```
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5000:" />
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use subdomains with localhost on IISExpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780091/how-to-use-subdomains-with-localhost-on-iisexpress)

Comment: @Win, apparently things are different in ASP.NET Core, so this question should remain open.